# NodeJS request library how to get the full URL including URI and query string params

Tags: node.js, node-request

How does one extract/find the full URL from a HTTP request performed with the NodeJS [request](https://github.com/request/request) library. This would be useful for logging purposes.

Here's a code example to demonstrate:

```
request({
    baseUrl: 'https://foo.bar',
    url: '/foobar',
    qs: {
        page: 1,
        pagesize: 25
    }
}, (err, res, body) => {
    // Somewhere here I'd expect to find the full url from one of the parameters above
    // Expected output: https://foo.bar/foobar?page=1&pagesize=25
    console.log(res);
});
```

I can't seem to find any properties of the `res` param in the callback that contains the URL.

To clarify: by full URL I mean the URL constructed by the request library which should include the following fields:

- Base URL (or just URI/URL when no base URL was set)
- URL (or URI)
- Query string parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can easily do that with store your request when you create it.

```
const request = require('request');
const myReq = request({
    baseUrl: 'https://foo.bar',
    url: '/foobar',
    qs: {
        page: 1,
        pagesize: 25
    }
}, (err, res, body) => {
    console.log(myReq.host); // BASE URL
    console.log(myReq.href); // Request url with params
});
```

Comment: Ok, that was so obvious that I missed it... Thx!